# angularjs replace array key with value

Tags: php, angularjs

i want to replace an array key with the value. here is my array.

```
[
   {"COLUMN_NAME":"ID"},
   {"COLUMN_NAME":"project_name"},
   {"COLUMN_NAME":"Population"},
   {"COLUMN_NAME":"project_id"},
   {"COLUMN_NAME":"Date"},
   {"COLUMN_NAME":"location"}
]
```

what i am hoping to get is an array like this

```
[
   {"ID":"ID"},
   {"project_name":"project_name"},
   {"Population":"Population"},
   {"project_id":"project_id"},
   {"Date":"Date"},
   {"location":"location"}
]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: in JS or PHP ? and share your try also ?

Comment: have you **tried anything yourself** so far? if yes, *edit* your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can using this code:

delete yourarray[0];
yourarray.push({ID2:"ID2"});

This resolve.

Comment: worked as described. thanks

Comment: Nice! I'm happy to help!